# java regex: find pattern of 1 or more numbers followed by a single

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a java regex problem.

how can I find pattern of 1 or more numbers followed by a single . in a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the answer to your question:

```
String searchText = "asdgasdgasdg a121341234.sdg asdg as12..dg a1234.sdg ";
searchText.matches("\\d+\\.[^.]");
```

This will match "121341234." and "1234." but not "12."

Comment: I am also wondering why [^.]   The answer given is helpful but considering the very cryptic nature of the code, more explanation would be nice.

Comment: @JamisonMan111 \\.[^.] basically means "dot followed by anything except dot". [^.] means anything but dot.

Answer (score 10):

```
"^[\\d]+[\\.]$"

^     = start of string
[\\d] = any digit
+     = 1 or more ocurrences
\\.   = escaped dot char
$     = end of string
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(\\d)+\\.
```

`\\d` represents  any digit
`+` says one or more

Refer this http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: The dot must be escaped, or it will match any single character rather than `.` you should use `\\.`

Answer (score 1):

In regex the metacharacter `\d` is used to represent an integer but to represent it in a java code as a regex one would have to use `\\d` because of the double parsing performed on them.

First a string parser which will convert it to `\d` and then the regex parser which will interpret it as an integer metacharacter (which is what we want).

For the "one or more" part we use the `+` greedy quantifier.

To represent a `.` we use `\\.` because of the double parsing scenario.

So in the end we have `(\\d)+(\\.)`.

Answer (score 0):

`\\d+)\\.`

`\\d` is for numbers, `+` is for one and more, `\\.` is for dot. If `.` is written without backslash before it it matches *any* character.